# Adding Logo to NavBar Creates Gap before 1st Item in NavBar and Dropdown Menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is first time using Bootstrap and am relatively new to HTML/CSS. When I inserted logo into the navbar, the first item in my navigation list "Home" has a gap appearing before it that I cannot figure out how to get rid of. This space goes away when I delete logo so is somehow related. Similar issues carries over onto dropdown menu where"HOME" is indented whereas rest of navigation is not.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is HTML

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class ="container">

        <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle ="collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href ="#" ><img src="images/PermitMeLogoHorz.png"</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Wireless Communications <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Site Acquisition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Land Use Consulting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Permit Expediting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
            </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

      </div>    
</div>
```

And here is CSS

```
.navbar-brand > img{
width:100%;
margin-top:5px;
```

}

```
.navbar-nav li a {
color: #CCC000;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:400;
padding-top:25px;
```

}

```
.navbar .nav .active > a, .navbar .nav .active > a:hover {
background-color: #fff;
color:black;
height:60px;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
color: #b20000;
```

}

```
.dropdown  ul li a{
color:black;
```

}

```
.dropdown li a:hover{
background-color:gray ;
color:white;
```

}

```
.caret{
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-top: 8px solid #b20000;
margin-top:-2px;
```

}

Comment: From your code sample it looks like you are missing the closing tag for the image.